# When I select categoy menu or any page I get following error message "Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons" Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4.2

When I select category or when I click on menu I get the foollowing error.
Need Help to understand and fix the following error please...

```
{"0":"Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\\Search\\Model\\EngineResolver, Argument 2 passed to Magento\\Search\\Model\\EngineResolver::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in \/home\/misik\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php on line 121","1":"#1 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Compiled.php:150]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Compiled.php:79]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Compiled.php:150]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Compiled.php:79]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Compiled.php:150]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Compiled.php:79]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog-search\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Fulltext\/Collection.php:207]\n#9 Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection->__construct() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/CatalogSearch\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Fulltext\/Collection\/Interceptor.php:14]\n#10 Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection\\Interceptor->__construct() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:121]\n#11 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Compiled.php:108]\n#12 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:56]\n#13 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->create() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Product\/CollectionFactory.php:43]\n#14 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\CollectionFactory->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog-search\/Model\/Layer\/Category\/ItemCollectionProvider.php:36]\n#15 Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\Layer\\Category\\ItemCollectionProvider->getCollection() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Model\/Layer.php:146]\n#16 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Layer->getProductCollection() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct.php:481]\n#17 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->initializeProductCollection() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct.php:121]\n#18 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->_getProductCollection() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct.php:366]\n#19 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->getIdentities() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct\/Interceptor.php:113]\n#20 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct\\Interceptor->getIdentities() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/Layout\/LayoutPlugin.php:96]\n#21 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\Layout\\LayoutPlugin->afterGetOutput() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:146]\n#22 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#23 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php:347]\n#24 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Page.php:258]\n#25 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page->render() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Layout.php:171]\n#26 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Layout->renderResult() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#27 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#28 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#29 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Result\/Page\/Interceptor.php:95]\n#30 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:120]\n#31 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:23]\n#32 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:263]\n#33 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub\/index.php:44]\n","url":"\/technology\/computer.html","script_name":"\/pub\/index.php","report_id":"6cfed32645c16692e6f4cc895bd8260068b3e31724c2b0f8bdcd089455df475d"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder pub/errors find file local.xml.sample
Rename the file local.xml.sample to local.xml in the same folder pub/errors
Also, set developer mode using the following command :

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

You will then see the exact cause of the problem

Comment: Okay Thank you I will check

Comment: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Search\Model\EngineResolver, Argument 2 passed to Magento\Search\Model\EngineResolver::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121

Comment: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Search\Model\EngineResolver, Argument 2 passed to Magento\Search\Model\EngineResolver::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121

Comment: You need to compile your dependency injection that is di.xml Try this:
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Yes!! very good now.. thank you!!!

Comment: I'm delighted to be able to help you!